# How to modify the implementation of x86 assembly instructions on QEMU Virtual Machine

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, rdtsc

I want to modify the implementation of `rdtsc` assembly instruction, i.e., I want to modify at the fundamental level, what happens when `rdtsc` assembly instruction is invoked.

I am working on a **QEMU Virtual Machine** running on an **Intel Core2 Duo** processor. The **Instruction Set Architecture** is `i686`.

To locate the portion of **QEMU** Source Code dealing with `rdtsc` call, I did a `grep` over the entire source code and found the function `helper_rdtsc()` in the file `target-i386/misc_helper.c` to be the key suspect. So I did the following modification in this file:

```
.
.

/* modification start at header inclusion */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
static const uint64_t myconst = 81926483;
/* modification end at header inclusion */
.
.

void helper_rdtsc(CPUX86State *env)
{
    uint64_t val;

    if ((env->cr[4] & CR4_TSD_MASK) && ((env->hflags & HF_CPL_MASK) != 0)) {
        raise_exception(env, EXCP0D_GPF);
    }
    cpu_svm_check_intercept_param(env, SVM_EXIT_RDTSC, 0);

    val = cpu_get_tsc(env) + env->tsc_offset;

    /* modification start within helper_rdtsc() */
    val = val % myconst;
    printf("rdtsc return = %" PRIu64 "//printed from source code\n", val);
    /* modification end within helper_rdtsc() */

    env->regs[R_EAX] = (uint32_t)(val);
    env->regs[R_EDX] = (uint32_t)(val >> 32);
}
```

Then I compiled **QEMU** from this modified source code, mounted **Ubuntu 12.04** as the Guest-OS, and ran a test `C` code which accessed `rdtsc` through the following function:

```
int64_t myrdtsc(void)
{
    int64_t tick;
    asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=A" (tick));
    return tick;
}
```

Naturally, on executing this test code, I expected the value returned through `tick` to be less than `myconst`. Also I expected the statement `rdtsc return = <somevalue> //printed from source code` to be printed as a part of the `rdtsc` call. However none of it happened.

Am I modifying the right portion of the **QEMU** source code? If yes, is there an error in the modifications I have made? If no, where should I look for in the source code to do the desired modification?

Comment: You mean the way qemu implements that instruction, or the way it executes on the host hardware? The latter involves applying for a job at Intel and convincing the management that changing meaning of well known commands is a good idea. The former involves digging in the QEMU sources; it's open source.

Comment: @sevaalekseyev I meant the former one. I have tried digging in the QEMU source code and even attempted several changes, but all in vain. Hence, I wished if someone could point where exactly should I look for in the source code. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching the code for "rdtsc"? A quick grep seems to indicate helper_rdtsc in target-i386/misc_helper.c as a likely candidate

Comment: Have you tried searching for string "rdtsc" in them? :)

Comment: @doynax - Yeah, I did a grep and just like you, I too found helper_rdtsc in target-i386/misc_helper.c as the most probable candidate. However doing the desired modifications and then recompiling QEMU from the source code, didn't give the expected results, indicating that helper_rdtsc in target-i386/misc_helper.c is not probably what I am looking for.

Comment: @hardcoder: That sort of work might have been worth sharing in your post you know. I don't suppose you're using the KVM version or anything?

Comment: Nope, I didn't use the KVM version.

Comment: I have tested with a simple real-mode bootsector code, and indeed you found the right function and I could make it return whatever I wanted.

Comment: @Jester - So do you mean there is an error in the modifications I made? Because when I compiled the QEMU from this modified source code, I didn't get the return value I was expecting.

Comment: The modification seems fine, you are probably not running it due to bad build or different qemu binary being used (or kvm as doynax suggested). Attach gdb to qemu and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Well,in fact,I find another place which is more suspicious:target-i386/translate.c.After I add a printf there and recompile&&install it.I got nothing I want.So I guess you have to do your job down to the VMM level,which says KVM source code.